# Delimiting Data (fixed width) when number of rows will change

Tags: vba

I've been trying to piece this code together through macro recording and discussion forums and I can't seem to figure out what my problem is.

I am by no means an Excel professional, but I've looked around the web quite a bit and can't figure out how to solve this. 
The current error I'm getting is:

> "No data was selected to parse".

The code in double asterisks is what's highlighted in the debugger:

```
Sub Delimit_ImportARData()
 '
 'Delimit_ImportARData Macro
 '

 '
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    **With Range("D1:D" & LastRow)
    .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(26, 1)),
    TrailingMinusNumbers _:=True
    End With**
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ALPHALOC"
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BU"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Southwest AR  7Jan_20_17.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("AR Southwest").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("V2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't believe that your destination can be the same as the source.

Answer (score 0):

May not be your problem, but the following line certainly requires attention...

```
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(26, 1)),
```

should be...

```
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(26, 1)), _
```

Answer (score 0):

the error consist in the block of 'with' sentence, change this:

```
**With Range("D1:D" & LastRow)
    .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(26, 1)),
    TrailingMinusNumbers _:=True
    End With**
```

for this:

```
 With Range("D1:D" & LastRow)
     .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D2"), dataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
     FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(26, 1)), _
     TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End With
```

the error is generated when you try to use many lines to put the parameters of "TextToColumns"method.

note that in the end of the line "FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(26, 1))," you must to write "_" after the comma, to indicate that the parameters continues in the next line. Too, in the sentence "TrailingMinusNumbers *:=True" ,the sign "*" remains.

I hope this help you.

Humberto